# What is the effect of break; in this code

Tags: c, c-strings

I have a program that encodes a given string in ROT13 encoding. However, I realized that the encoding is partially wrong if I do not add a `break;` somewhere in the `if statement`
I'd like to understand why. See code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s1[] = "ROT13 (\"rotate by 13 places\", sometimes hyphenated ROT-13) is a simple letter substitution cipher.\n";
    char s2[] = "ROT13 (\"rotate by 13 places\", sometimes hyphenated ROT-13) is a simple letter substitution cipher.\n";
    char codec[] = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ";
    char ROT13[] = "nNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZaAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmM";
    int i =0;
    int j =0;

    printf("%s\n",s1);  //prints source string
    
    for (i = 0; s1[i] !='\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; codec[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s1[i] == codec[j]) {
                s1[i] = ROT13[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", s1);   //Output after ROT13 encoding
    
    for (i = 0; s2[i] !='\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; codec[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s2[i] == codec[j]) {
                s2[i] = ROT13[j];
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", s2);   //Output after ROT13 encoding

    return 0;

}
```

The result after compilation.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`break;` makes it get out of the loop.

For example, when the plaintext is `c`, it is encrypted to `p`, and if there isn't the `break;`, the scanning goes on, find `p`, and encrypt that to `c` again.

The `break;` is for preventing this kind of double encryption.

Comment: Lest there be any confusion, `break` causes control to leave the *innermost* containing loop (or `switch`, but there are none of those in the OP's code).

Answer (score 0):

You need the `break` in the second character match loop for the same reason that you have a `break` in the first character match loop. If you find a character in `codec` which matches the current character in the input string, you replace the character found in the input string, either `s1` or `s2`. You then need to advance to the next character in the input string by exiting the character match loop immediately after replacing the character.

If you don't advance to the next character in the input string after replacing the current character in the input string then you may match the replacement character and do a second rotation. Whether you do a second rotation or not depends on the character being matched.

Example: If the character in the input string is `'A'` which is then replaced by `'N'` and you continue looking for a match, you will find `'N'` and you will then replace the original character `'A'` which has already been replaced by `'N'`, a second time with `'A'`. This double replacement will rotate the input character by 13 and then by 13 again, doing two rotations.

You will get lucky with characters that are after the 13th character, either `'M'` or `'m'`, because those characters rotate to a character in the first part of the alphabet and so those characters will not go through the double replacement.

You might also consider this alternative implementation which uses the `strchr()` Standard C Library function to replace the innermost loop that performs the character match operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    // the codec contains characters arranged so that the replacement character
    // for a character in the codec is the position of the matching character
    // plus 13. We do this by having the characters in ascending order from
    // letter A to letter Z then duplicating the first 13 characters of the
    // alphabet after the letter Z. This allows us to find a match and then
    // just add 13 to the index to find the replacement character.
    // WARNING: This array of alphabetic characters is designed to be used
    //          with the strchr() function which find only the first matching
    //          character so duplicating the first 13 characters doesn't matter.
    char codec2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn";
    char s1[] = "ROT13 (\"rotate by 13 places\", sometimes hyphenated ROT-13) is a simple letter substitution cipher.\n";
    char s2[] = "ROT13 (\"rotate by 13 places\", sometimes hyphenated ROT-13) is a simple letter substitution cipher.\n";

    printf("%s\n", s1);  //prints source string

    for (int i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char* p;
        if (p = strchr(codec2, s1[i])) {
            // found a matching character so replace it.
            // codec2[] contains the replacement character 13 positions after
            // the matching character.
            s1[i] = *(p + 13);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", s1);   //Output after ROT13 encoding

    for (int i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char* p;
        if (p = strchr(codec2, s2[i])) {
            s2[i] = *(p + 13);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", s2);   //Output after ROT13 encoding

    return 0;
}
```